# Factorial will not multiply

Tags: javascript

When I run the code it doesn't multiply my number it just outputs in a loop until it reaches 1

I have tried multiple different ways and this one is the closest i've gotten

```
    ......................................
    var BR="<br />"; //html line break

    function factorial(Num) {

   document.write("The factorial of your number is" +Num +BR);

   if (Num == 1 ) return 1;

   else return (Num * factorial(Num-1));

    }
.....................................................        





   .......................................
        var Num; //users number
        var Numfactorial;
        var ES="";
               var factorial                     
        Num=prompt("Enter a number between 1-20" +ES);
        Numfactorial=factorial(Num);
     .........................................
```

It's supposed to take the number and multiply it down, so say you put in 20 it should go 19*18*17... down until it multiplies 1 and then outputs the product.

Comment: You put `document.write("The factorial of your number is" +Num +BR);` in the `factorial` function, so the browser will update the output every time the function is called (which is multiple times since you use recursion). If you only want to print the final result then you should move `documen.write` outside the function.

Comment: okay... now it just puts out the number that I put in

Answer (score 0):

Place the `document.write` outside your function, and just print the result (`Numfactorial`) to the page. You also need to parse `Num` to a number, and remove `var factorial`:

```
var BR = "<br />";
function factorial(Num) {
    if (Num == 1) return 1;
    else return Num * factorial(Num - 1);
}
var Num;
var Numfactorial;
var ES = "";
Num = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 1-20" + ES));
Numfactorial = factorial(Num);
document.write("The factorial of your number is " + Numfactorial + BR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is the expected output of your code. Your function factorial is returning your value which you aren't using to display the value. You should instead write it like this:

```
....................................................
var BR="<br />"; //html line break
function factorial(Num) {
   if (Num == 1 ) return 1;
   else return (Num * factorial(Num-1));
}
.....................................................



.......................................
    var Num; //users number
    var Numfactorial;
    var ES="";
           var factorial                     
    Num=prompt("Enter a number between 1-20" +ES);
    Numfactorial=factorial(Num);
    document.write("The factorial of your number is" +Numfactorial +BR);
 .........................................
```

Comment: Sorry guys I was really tired and wasn't thinking thank you so much for the help and quick reply's!